# How to read data at server side sent by HttpPost

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-post

I'm working on creating sample application which sends a XML file to the local server. In the server side I need to read the data which is sent by client and write it into a new file.

Below is the client side code I'm using to read a XML file and send it to the server.

```java
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Below code is used to connect with the local tomact server or servlet
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy");
        File file = new File("C:\\Files\\sample.xml");
        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                new FileInputStream(file), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        int respcode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("respcode: " + respcode);
```

Kindly let me know by using **tomact** how to fetch the data from the client and write it into the server side. Do I need to use servlets to handle this?

I had visited many blogs but I'm not getting how to create a server side code to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to write a servlet/filter to handle this. Once your servlet receives the `HttpServletRequest` object,

You can read it using `HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()` method

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'll try using the above. I have one more question that 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy' the connection url which I'm mentioning in the client side should contain which url? for the port I can specify the tomcat port. But what about the url?